# Can I Assign A value from javascript to asp.net server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have table with dynamic created labels in it and I want the label width equals too the td cell above it by any mean . I think of getting the td by javascript and set the variable in asp.net but it didn't work . All that in page load.

```
window.onload = function() {
var td1= document.getElementById('td1').offsetWidth;
document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = td1;
);

<table id="tabel1" class="style8" border="2">
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">
            0:00<br />
            0:00<br />
            0
            </td>
        <td id="td2">
           9:00<br />
            9:45<br />
            1
        </td>
```

Comment: Nope. You cannot set a value from JavaScript to ASP as ASP is SERVER side and will be processed before JavaScript. You are to find another way.

Comment: then how could I make the label and td cell equals

Comment: Try setting `runat="server"` attribute to those _td_ s. And use `document.getElementById('<%= td1.ClientID %>')` in the js.

Comment: @mshsayem the td tag become as variable with no values

Comment: the problem still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax Solved this problem , If you want a value from client side to be submitted to server side you should use ajax to send data , send the td by ajax to server side and set the variable in asp.net then return the result to client side that will work